# iPad: Get User Location

Tags: ios, ipad, gps, core-location

I am working on an application that needs the location of where the user is entering information. This iOS application may run on iPhone and iPad. Given that iPhone typically come with cellular service and thus a GPS chip I don't think this will be an issue. However what about iPad? If I am developing for iPad (**that will not have cellular service**) how will I be able to retrieve the user's current GPS location. This would be easy to do with the `CoreLocation` framework if I knew I had that capability, but on iPad I can't always be certain it will be there.

How would I get around this to get the GPS coordinates, or some other way of getting the user's relative location?

Comment: If you need gps level location accuracy then you will need to use iPads with cellular capability.  It is up to you whether you restrict the application installation through UIDeviceCapabilities or merely advise your users of the recommended hardware. Note that the iPad doesn't need to have an active cellular service, it just needs the gps hardware that is fitted to cellar models. You can also use an add on gps unit https://www.ozpilot.com.au/Bad-Elf-GPS-for-Lightning-Connector?gclid=CL_U_svB-tMCFdWkvQod6-4FYg. This also makes location available through core location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location services are available even on iPad, using WiFi.

Take a look at this Article from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Specifically, you can set up your app to require either location services, or to require a GPS:

> Requiring the Presence of Location Services in an iOS App
>
> If your iOS app requires location services to function properly,
>   include the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the app’s Info.plist
>   file. The App Store uses the information in this key to prevent users
>   from downloading apps to devices that don’t contain the listed
>   features.
>
> The value for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is an array of strings
>   indicating the features that your app requires. Two strings are
>   relevant to location services:
>
> - Include the location-services string if you require location
>     services in general.
> - Include the gps string if your app requires
>     the accuracy offered only by GPS hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sources in IOS devices to get user location, one is through "GPS" and the other one is "WIFI". Your must be having one of them to retrieve user's location. If your IPad is connected to a "WIFI network" even if it doesn't have a cellular connection, then it's not an issue.

Comment: It may well be an issue. Wifi location accuracy may be much lower than gps-based location; accuracy may be in the order of kilometres or not even available

Comment: Yeah that's true. Wifi just gives you the coordinates based on your internet "IP Address".